# Image is not updating after overwriting

Tags: php, image, ffmpeg

I have a video hosting site. There a video is successfully uploaded with a specific frame thumbnail by ffmpeg-php. But when editing the thumbnail, Choosing an another thumbnail is overwriting the previous thumbnail. But when I load the page the old thumbnail is loading, not the updated thumbnail. But when I open the image through filemanager(CPanel) it is showing as updated image.
I have tried clearing cache in my browser and tried on multiple devices. But same old image is loading. Any solution to this ?

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I have created a different path for the edited thumbnail. I think it is caching issue.